# ForIn to merge object configurations

Tags: javascript

Why can't I run a ForIn to merge the configs on a constructor?

I have got this tiny class that has a bunch of open configurations, so I would like to simply run a ForIn in order to shorten the code.

Basically turn this

```
var FormMessage = (function() {

    ...

    function FormMessage(args) {
        this.Conf = {
            mobile:args.mobile || Configurations.mobile,
            form: { 
                selector: args.form.selector || Configurations.formSelector
            },
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    return FormMessage;
})();

var i = new FormMessage({mobile: true, form:{selector: '.the-first'}}),
    e = new FormMessage({mobile: false, form:{selector: '.the-second'}});
```

into this

```
var FormMessage = (function() {
    ...
    function FormMessage(args) {
        for (var attr in args) { this.Conf[attr] = args[attr]; }
    }
    ...

    return FormMessage;
})();

var i = new FormMessage({mobile: true, form:{selector: '.the-first'}}),
    e = new FormMessage({mobile: false, form:{selector: '.the-second'}});
```

But for if I do this then the second time I initialize the object it will override the first one.

Do you guys know how can I make this work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No. It is suppose to be a single object where every property is optional and should default to something if not passed while initializing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps along something like the code below? I also think that the IIFE is unnecessary.

```js
function FormMessage(conf, args) {
    Object.keys(args).forEach(e => conf[e] = args[e]);
    return Object.assign({}, conf); // returns a fresh new object
}
// initial config object
var confObj = {mobile: 'wow'};
var i = new FormMessage(confObj, {mobile: true, form:{selector: '.the-first'}}),
    e = new FormMessage(confObj, {mobile: false, form:{selector: '.the-second'}});

console.log(i, e);
```